# Override Account Setting Footer for some email messages - Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We have setup a HTML footer in Account Settings in Marketing Cloud.
For some emails, we want to use a custom footer and override the Account Settings footer.
When I create an email message using an existing Marketing Cloud template and insert my custom footer, I still see the Account Settings footer.
How do I switch it off or override it for that particular email without going back and forth to my Account Settings?

I have used the code

```
%%[ IF 0 == 1 THEN ]%%
%%profile_center_url%%
%%unsub_center_url%%
%%Member_Busname%%
%%Member_Addr%%
%%Member_City%%
%%Member_State%%
%%Member_PostalCode%%
%%Member_Country%%
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

but this only works for Paste HTML emails or if you save it in Account Settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try setting a variable to show/hide the footer in account settings. Then define that variable in the email where you want to hide it. For example, in your account settings footer:

```
%%[ if @hideFooter == “true” then ]%%
%%[ else ]%%
[HTML Footer goes here]
%%[ ending ]%%
```

In your email:

```
%%[ set @hideFooter = “true” ]%%
```